# bpy create text

Tags: python, text-object

im using Blender 2.9.2 and trying to learn how to create text. Have a list of words (around 80) I will like to have automatically created via script. The one basic example wont run. I get and error message telling me to look at the console but nothing meaningful is there.

```
import bpy

t1 = bpy.data.curves.new("message", "FONT")
o1 = bpy.data.objects.new("message", t1)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(o1)
o1.location = (0,0,3)
t1.body = "Hi there!"

t1.extrude = 0.1
```

Is it because im using 2.9.2? What is there that I need to correct to run this very simple code? (taken from here: [http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/create-text.html](http://web.purplefrog.com/%7Ethoth/blender/python-cookbook/create-text.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks like it is from before 2.8 but wherever it is from you need to change the link line to use `collection` rather than `scene`:

```py
import bpy

t1 = bpy.data.curves.new("message", "FONT")
o1 = bpy.data.objects.new("message", t1)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(o1)
o1.location = (0,0,3)
t1.body = "Hi there!"

t1.extrude = 0.1
```

should work in 2.8 or later versions of Blender.  I just tested it in 3.1.2

Comment: Great, many thanks it works!

Comment: @funkz you're welcome.  Enjoy scripting.